# Gradle task: Copy dependencies, rename and unarchive

Tags: gradle, groovy

My requirement is download java dependencies from maven and rename every jar to be extracted and renamed to a different name.

```
task downloadOutput() { 
  doLast {
    def downloadsDir = "${buildDir}/output/"
    copy {
      from configurations.mydependencies
      rename { fileName -> filename + "-l2"
        
      }
      into file(downloadsDir)
    }
  }
}
```

Adding `from zipTree (configuration.mydependencies)` also fails with the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':downloadOutput'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: configuration ':mydependencies'.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
    - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
    - A File instance.
    - A Path instance.
    - A Directory instance.
    - A RegularFile instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.
```

How to fix this zipTree? Is there a different method or api?

Comment: How does it fail? Please add the error message / stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @LukasKörfer - added stacktrace as well.